# Visual studio 2010, include openssl problem

Tags: c++

I used :

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
```

in vs 2010 and have a problem with it. The compiler could not recognized it. 
How could I include it?

Comment: Have you added the include dir to your project, in the project properties?

Answer (score 1):

A simple rule of thumb to check if your options/code are okay or not is to remember the way compiler (actually the pre-proccessor) handles #includes. Quite simply:

```
for every #included file xxx/yyy.h
    for every include path inc_path specified (e.g. via -I)
        if inc_path/xxx/yyy.h exists
            // found;
            // break;
if not found
    // error
```

so either "xxx" is wrong, or inc_path is not part of your build options.